# Leiningen compiling error with Java files that reference classes generated from Clojure files

Tags: java, compilation, clojure, interop, leiningen

I have a Leiningen project that is compiling both Java and Clojure files.  The Java files import some of the classes that are generated from the Clojure files (with gen-class).

When I do lein compile, I get compilation errors on the imports in the Java files (saying it can't find the classes).  If I remove the Java files from the project, do lein compile, add the Java files back, and do lein compile again, everything works fine.

So, it's like the Clojure files need to be compiled before the Java files.

By the way, I am including the Clojure files that gen classes in the :aot list.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Probably won't help you right now but I've found its usually easier to make Clojure depend on Java, and avoid dependencies the other way round. And note that cyclic dependencies in polyglot projects are particularly nasty...

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I'm having basically the same problem, trying to address it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205723/sandwiching-clojure-between-java-with-leiningen/13205871#13205871).

Comment: I don't remember to tell you the truth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(The code in this answer is untested, although it should hopefully work with Leiningen 1.x (for recent values of x).)*

Leiningen's `compile` task runs the `javac` task automatically if your `project.clj` specifies a `:java-source-path`. It does so prior to compiling Clojure sources, because I suppose that's the usual direction of the dependency.

To get around this, you could use a hook:

```
;;; in leiningen.hooks.clj_first.clj

(ns leiningen.hooks.clj-first
  (:require [leiningen.compile :as leinc]
            [leiningen.javac :as javac]))

(defn compile-clj-first-hook [compile-task project & args]
  (apply compile-task
         (dissoc project :java-source-path)
         args))
  (javac/javac project))

(add-hook #'leiningen.compile/compile compile-clj-first-hook)
```

Place this somewhere on your build-time classpath and add

```
:hooks [clj-first-hook]
```

to your project map.

Note that `javac`, when called directly, will still not call `compile`. You could also make it equivalent to `compile` e.g. by hooking it with the following function:

```
(defn javac-hook [javac-task project]
  (if (project ::clj-compiled?)
    (javac/javac project)
    (leinc/compile project)))
```

The last form of `compile-clj-first-hook` would then need to be

```
(javac/javac (assoc project ::clj-compiled? true))
```

(Making `compile` *not* call `javac` at all would probably break `jar` / `uberjar`.)

Comment: Any chance you could review an attempted implementation of your solution as a plugin in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205723/sandwiching-clojure-between-java-with-leiningen/13205871#13205871)?  I had trouble following where to put the code you suggested. (I am very new to build tools).  Thanks!